# legalization of stay in Poland after getting negative decision

Tags: legal, poland

I am Arun from India. I came to Germany on a business visa and after I applied for *Temporary Residence Permit* (TRC) in Poland in march 2018 but in october 2018 I got a negative decision. my lawyer did appeal. after waiting 2 years I did not get any response from the migration office. after that this Feb 2021 I knew through my employer I got the negative decision on 18 Jan 2021. when I tried to contact my lawyer. she refused to give my negative decision. Now I am in the worst situation what should I do in this situation.

Comment: We can not say that because while you talk about your visa, we have no clue about your financial, employment and current visa situation. You definitely have a right to get the decision.

Comment: @Arun Where is your lawyer based? It sounds strange that a Poland-based lawyer would refuse to give you the decision, what reason did they give for refusing? What has your employer told you about the decision exactly? Have they taken any action to terminate your employment if you do not have a work visa?